# How to Reduce Video Size - iOS Titanium Video?

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am developing an iOS application in Titanium Appcelerator and using inbuilt camera to record a 2-5 minutes video. Once the video is recorded it needs to be passed to a PHP Web application via REST API. However the size of this video is too big [almost 100 Mb] to be transferred successfully.I am looking for a way to either compress the video or reduce its size to be able to upload successfully.Your suggestions are valuable , so kindly let me know what is the best way forward.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You could try a module developed by me: [ti.ios.trim](https://github.com/martintietz/ti.ios.trim) (originally built to do video trimming, but it also supports video compression). You could leave out the startTime and the endTime parameters and do something like the following:

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    mediaTypes: [Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO],
    success: function(e) {
      var tempFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, new Date().getTime() +'-'+ _.random(0,1000) +'.mov');
      tempFile.write(e.media);

      compressVideo(tempFile.resolve());
    }
});

function compressVideo(pathToVideoFile) {
    var trimmer = require('ti.ios.trim');
    trimmer.trimVideo({
        input: pathToVideoFile,
        quality: 1, // use 1 for high compression or 2 for medium compression
        success: function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('SUCCESS:');
            Ti.API.info('path to the compressed file: '+ e.videoURL);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            Ti.API.error('ERROR:');
            Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
}
```

---

Comment: unfortunately, this has an xcode 11 bug where it crashes and no longer works on iOS 13.x